# WordPress import not importing custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, import

I've posted this already in the [WP Support Forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-import-not-importing-custom-taxonomy) hoping to have more luck here.

I'm trying to import a custom post type from one blog to another. (126 posts in the custom post type).

I've exported using WordPress' export function from WP version 3.3.2 and trying to import into 3.2.1.

I can get all the posts to import into the correct custom post type, but none of my custom taxonomy or meta information is being imported in.

In both WPs I have the exact same name for each of my custom post types and taxonomies, I literally copied/pasted my functions.php over.

Any idea why my import is adding all posts of my custom post type but not my custom taxonomy? Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot update the destination WordPress installation to WordPress 3.3.2 as well?

Comment: No real reason, I'm just not ready to do an upgrade at this point. It's a larger, popular site so I like to do major upgrades only. I would probably do it though if I knew for sure it would solve this problem...

Comment: Could you not take a copy and do an upgrade to 4.0 locally, and if nothing breaks upgrade the live site? It would certainly improve your chances of an answer, and may even solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I belive you exporting custom content right? If yes, you will fail to import any taxonomy (tag or category or whatever)...

in your export file not exists wp:terms items which is responsible for terms import. bug? perhaps.

what you can do without big or small code changes (i did reasearch this particular tsk) you can export full blog. copy  that you want to see in other blog. paste it to same place of custom post type export file and import it again...

at least this will help you to import all terms of assigned category.

Comment: Are you saying that custom taxonomy is never imported with custom post types?

I've looked in my export xml file and the custom taxonomy terms are in there... they just aren't getting imported.

Comment: My dev envoiropment for 3.3 version is 3.3.3 so i asume it's should be almost same as yours. If i export custom post type TERMS isn't there. even if thay created assigned to a post type i try to export. Check your exported file... do you have <wp:term> tags inside that point to your terms? if no... i have a sad news for you... in your export file exported terms not exists.

check with export all and export custom post type options.

Comment: I don't have <wp:term> tags, I do have <category domain="my_custom_taxonomy"... tags

Comment: just to be clear... last time. wordpress will import terms only if in import file will be found <wp:term> tags (data inside that tags).

if you will do a full export you will see that data and will be able to copy/paste it to your custom post type export file.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.  I did a full export this time instead of just exporting my custom post type.

This resulted in an .xml file which did indeed have a big list of <wp:term> tags at the top of the file.

Unfortunately, they still didn't import.  I got all of the posts but none of the custom taxonomy.  Any idea why?

Comment: no. wp:term **perfectly imported** if thay fund at the export file.